# Arbitrary HTTP 501 Not Implemented errors in Tomcat due to SOAP Envelope/Header mixup

Tags: java, http, tomcat, soap

we're encountering strange "501 not implemented" errors on a machine (Ubunut 12.04.4 LTS) we've set up for test purposes. The server web application is running in a Tomcat 7.0.55 (tested with other 7.x version as well) and with Java 7 resp. Java 8 (20) (several versions tested). We're using Jax WS 2.2.8 on the server side. Requests can have very different sizes, complexities, etc.

Approximately 1% of all SOAP requests (out of several thousands) end up with in the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 501: Not Implemented
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:272)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.addToIndex(Unknown Source)
    at com.jv.pm.server.ReIndexService$IndexThread.run(ReIndexService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

On server side, Tomcat logs the following:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2014:22:10:41 +0200] "/S:Envelope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1148
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2014:09:41:59 +0200] "></S:Envelope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1164
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2014:09:48:55 +0200] "dy></S:Envelope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1168
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2014:14:16:41 +0200] "velope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1138
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2014:16:24:26 +0200] "velope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1138
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2014:16:25:00 +0200] "velope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1138
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2014:16:25:37 +0200] "velope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1138
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2014:16:25:53 +0200] "velope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1138
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2014:16:28:43 +0200] ":Envelope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1144
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2014:19:35:02 +0200] "S:Envelope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1146
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2014:19:35:20 +0200] "></S:Envelope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1164
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2014:19:35:45 +0200] "dy></S:Envelope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1168
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Aug/2014:16:51:16 +0200] "Envelope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1142
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Aug/2014:16:51:40 +0200] "/S:Envelope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1148
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Aug/2014:17:35:29 +0200] "lope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1134
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2014:13:46:11 +0200] "pe>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1130
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2014:13:46:12 +0200] "pe>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1130
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2014:13:46:26 +0200] "ody></S:Envelope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1170
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Sep/2014:13:56:49 +0200] "nvelope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1140
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Sep/2014:13:57:03 +0200] "pe>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1130
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Sep/2014:13:57:28 +0200] "/S:Envelope>POST /application/methodname HTTP/1.1" 501 1148
```

As you can see, somehow the body of the HTTP message seems to be mixed up with the header (?). Even more strange: It happens on arbitrary connections and data, so one and the same request (carrying exactly the same data) can end up in a HTTP 501 response and a second later in a HTTP 200 response. So for us it feels to be indeterministic and we can only reproduce it reliably if we send several hundred or more requests to the server - there will be a reliable (roughly) 1 % of 501 errors.

We're facing the problem as well with a completely different web application which primarily deals with binary input data. So the problems seems to be completely independent from the running application or the structure of the SOAP requests.

It may be important to notice that the requests are running over the local loopback interface (so the client sending the SOAP requets runs on the same machine). On client-side, different Java versions (7 and 8) have been tested as well. Stub creation happened with "wsimport" (in Java 7).

We're somehow at our wits' end and we'd really appreciate if someone could lead us into the right direction to track this error down.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Hi Daniel , we're actually facing the same problem. Have you found any clue to resolve this issue ? Maybe by upgrading Tomcat ?

Comment: Yes an update to a new Tomcat version solved the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could solve the problem by updating to Apache Tomcat version 8.0.15.